# Javascript / window height - something?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
 24 <script type="text/javascript">
 25 
 26 function ToggleBlock($bShow){
 27         if($bShow)
 28                 $('.nkRelBlock').stop().css({
 29                         "transform": "translate3d(-20px,0,0)"
 30                 });
 31         else
 32                 $('.nkRelBlock').stop().css({
 33                         "transform": "translate3d(105%,0,0)"
 34                 });
 35 }
 36 
 37 $(document).ready(function(){
 38         var halfBody = $(window).height() / 9; // controls at which height the related block will display. body height / 8
 39         
 40         if($('body').height() > ($(window).height() + halfBody))
 41                 $(window).scroll(function( e ) {
 42                         
 43                                 if($(window).scrollTop() > halfBody)
 44                                         ToggleBlock(true);
 45                                 else
 46                                         ToggleBlock(false);
 47                 });
 48         else
 49                 ToggleBlock(true);
 50 });
 51 
 52 </script>
```

That makes an item of a website pop up once we scroll down.

I need to make it show later when scrolling, like for instance when we are at 100 px to reach the end of the page.

When  I play with that 9 nothing happens
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code a bit..

Run this code snippet and read the comments I placed there to better understand what I did.
It works pretty well but might need some tweaking in some cases.

To use it **Just scroll down until you see the pop up**

```js
function ToggleBlock($bShow) {
  // You can just use Show and Hide for animations
  if ($bShow) {
    $('.nkRelBlock').show(1000);
  } else {
    $('.nkRelBlock').hide(400);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Set Half Body (divide by 2)
  var halfBody = $('body').height() / 2;
  // Find the maximum possible scroll from top
  var maxScrollTop = $('body')[0].scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
  
  // Set on Scroll event
  $(window).scroll(function(e) {
    // Set common scroll factor which is the half body
    var scrollFactor = halfBody;

    if (halfBody - maxScrollTop > 0) {
      // In cases where the scroll is smaller than half the body e.g. when window and body height are rather small..
      scrollFactor = halfBody -maxScrollTop;
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > scrollFactor) {
      ToggleBlock(true);
    } else {
      ToggleBlock(false);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
 height: 1000px;
}
.nkRelBlock {
 margin-top: 0 !important;
 position: fixed;
 width:5vh;
 height: 5vh;
 background-color: red;
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 30px;
 border-radius: 10px;
    /* Start hidden initially */
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nkRelBlock">Hi!</div>
```

Comment: Thanks z-bone, looks awesome but this works if body height is set.
In my case I have no body height defined, the page grows with content.

Comment: @10000000 Well that's OK because whenever the content will add up the body size will grow on its own.. as long as there is enough scroll my solution should work.